# How to change the default location of data in HDFS to some permanent location?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running Hadoop in a pseudo-distributed single node cluster and I have a problem in changing the default location of data from /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/dfs/data to some permanent location which does not get cleared every time I reboot. I am new to Hadoop ecosystem.Any help will be highly apprciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [MCVE] to know more about how to ask questions. You need to provide more information like how is this data getting loaded to that directory etc. Thanks.

Comment: Okay will keep that in mind from next time. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `dfs.data.dir` in `hdfs-site.xml` should help.

By default it is set to `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`, that's why `/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/hadoop/dfs/data` in your case.

You cand find more information about HDFS configuration options in [hdfs-default.xml docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs-default.html).

You need to create a permanent directory where `hdfs user` has write privilege. lets say `/home/poulami/hadoopData/data` then you will need to add following in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
       <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
       <value>/home/poulami/hadoopData/data</value>
       <final>true</final>
</property>
```

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: The property is `dfs.namenode.name.dir` now (checked on hadoop 3.2.2)